# How to install webpart from outside the server?

Tags: 2007, web-part, administration

I would like to deploy a webpart on my sharepoint portal, but I don't have full access to the server sharepoint is installed on.

However, I have the "full control" authorization on all the subsite I am working on.
Is there a way to install a webpart locally, without having access to the server, or should I contact my system admin and ask him to deploy it ?

Comment: You have to ask to your system administrator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to have permissions on the server in order to deploy the webpart. The web part dll needs to be deployed to GAC or bin folder of the web application. Also, safe control entries need to be added to the web.config file. All these thing make it necessary to have permissions on the SharePoint server.

Comment: Just what I feared ... Thanks for the confirmation though !

Comment: You can up vote or mark the question as answered if you think it is helpful :-)

Comment: not yet :p apparently you have to wait 10 mn before marking a question as answered, and I don't have enough rep to upvote you ...